# Change broadcast time for NRF52832 with android app

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to change broadcast time with Nordic android application in NRF52832 beacon module? I've bought one in Aliexpress and they suggest that's possible but I have no idea how to do this.